# Finding duplicate books

Tags: php, algorithm, string-matching, similarity

I have a number of list of book's name along with their authors(no ISBN number). I want to maintain a single list containing unique entries of books and remove the duplicate entries of every book.

The problem I am facing is that the different list may follow different conventions to store the book's entries. For e.g - A list might store the author name in `last name` `first name` convention, in another list, the name entry of the book itself contains some addition information like the name of the series along with the sequence number.

Is there any standard algorithm to handle such type of problem? I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Right now I am using php to code the solution. As starters, I have tried `levenshtein, soundex, metaphone, similar_text` but none of them looks promising to me.

Example: Consider an example of [Inheritance Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_Cycle), the series contains four books. Now the entry of the second book of the series can be `Eldest`, `Eldest: The Inheritance Cycle (Book 2)`, `Eldest (Inheritance)`, `Eldest (Inheritance Cycle)`, `Inheritance 002: Eldest`.

Comment: This is a complex problem.  You can try to use a database of book titles and author names and do pattern recognition on the data.  I'd also look to see if there are any Amazon API's that could be used here.

Comment: Is there any free, up to date, book's database or some sort of subscription available?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a search problem, just with a more constrained domain. I would perhaps use an existing search technology (perhaps using [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) or [Solar](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)) and just iterate through the list, searching for a match first, and then if a sufficiently close one isn't found, adding the "document" (the info you have for one book) to the index.

It won't be a perfect answer, but it will give you a score for various matches, so it gives you some tuneable parameters to work with. This is an especially enticing solution if this is more than a 1-off problem that needs to be solved, since the "algorithm" can learn and tune itself as it goes if needed.